# W3 Schools Image slideshow order reversal

Tags: javascript, css

I've implemented the slideshow as shown on w3 schools http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp but I'm having an issue with the order in which it 'slides'.  I have combined the automatic slideshow with the slideshow indicators but when I load the page the order is 3, 2, 1. So the indicator is moving from right to left.  I've had no joy in figuring it out myself and so hope someone can help me.

```
<div class="imageContent">
                    <div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:670px">
                    <a href="mypage.php"><img class="mySlides" src="img/image1.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>
                    <a href="mypage.php"><img class="mySlides" src="img/image2.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>
                    <a href="mypage.php"><img class="mySlides" src="img/image3.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>
                    <div class="w3-center w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="w3-left w3-padding-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
                    <div class="w3-right w3-padding-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
                    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
                    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
                    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                var slideIndex = 1;

                showDivs(slideIndex);

                function plusDivs(n) {
                    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
                }

                function currentDiv(n) {
                    showDivs(slideIndex = n);
                }

                function showDivs(n) {
                    var i;

                    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
                    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
                    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
                    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                        x[i].style.display = "none";  
                    }
                    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
                    }
                    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";

                }

                carousel();

                function carousel() {

                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].style.display = "none"; 
                }
                slideIndex++;
                if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
                x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
                setTimeout(carousel, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
                plusDivs(1);
                }
                </script>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to replace plusDivs(1) with showDivs(slideIndex)

```
carousel();

            function carousel() {

            var i;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none"; 
            }
            slideIndex++;
            if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
            x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
            setTimeout(carousel, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
            showDivs(slideIndex);
            }
```